# mongodb lift class Snippet needs to be abstract

Tags: abstract-class, lift

I have implemented a mongodb-record based model, I am trying to code the form to store the data (event record) to the DB.

The snippet of the object to store is:

```
class eventSnippet extends StatefulSnippet with PaginatorSnippet[event] {

  var dispatch: DispatchIt = {
    case "editForm" => editForm _
  }

  var editingevent = event.createRecord


  def editForm(xhtml: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
        ("#editName" #> editingevent.title.toForm &
         "#editDescription" #> editingevent.description.toForm &
         "#editDT" #> editingevent.date_time.toForm &
         "#editCat" #> editingevent.category.toForm &
         "#editPrivacy" #> editingevent.privacy.toForm &
          "type=submit" #> SHtml.submit(?("Save"), () => save )).apply(xhtml)
  }

  def save = {
    editingevent.save
    redirectToHome
  }}
```

The error is:

```
class eventSnippet needs to be abstract, since:
[error] method page in trait Paginator of type => Seq[code.model.event] is not defined
[error] method count in trait Paginator of type => Long is not defined
```

While I change the class to abstract, It compiles, but I get an error on the browser:

```
Message: java.lang.InstantiationException
sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
```

I am using sbt 0.7.5 and Scala 2.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

Lift needs to make instances of your snippet, so it cannot be abstract.

I don't see anything in your snippet requiring pagination. You should simply remove the `with PaginatorSnippet[event]` and not make the class abstract.

If you do need pagination, you have to provide implementations for the `page` and `count` methods.

```
class eventSnippet extends StatefulSnippet with PaginatorSnippet[event] {
  def page: Seq[event] = // return itemsPerPage events, starting at curPage*itemsPerPage

  def count: Long = // return total count of events.

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Dave, I have removed the PaginatorSnippet[event] and abstract, It works fine now. Thanks a lot